# What do you call this tool and how do you enable it in word 2019?

Tags: microsoft-word

[image: word2019]

what do you call this tool and how do you enable it in word 2019? somehow I couldn't find it anymore.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.  The image is way to small, the circle is covering 40-60% of the icon, so identifying the icon won't be possible.

Comment: What happens when the tool is used?

Comment: All is good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are linking at is the tool that allows you to view two different parts of the same document. I believe it is sometimes referred to as the [horizontal split bar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/view-two-parts-of-a-document-at-the-same-time-in-word-for-mac-1adf3317-0ec4-4568-ad32-6f68b3e4b386) or [split window view](https://www.microassist.com/software-tips/word-2013-tip-split-window-view/).

An alternative method to get the same result is under the view ribbon.

You use that particular tool by clicking and dragging it down your scroll bar, it will split the page at the point where you leave it.

[image]

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thanks!